# Negative constant in Markov inequality?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, random-variables

> We have defined Markov inequality by
>
> Let be $X$ a non-negative random variable, $a\geq 0$ and $\varphi:[0,\infty[~\longrightarrow~]0,\infty[$ a monotonically increasing function, then
> $$
> P(X\geq a)\leq \frac{\mathbb{E}(\varphi(X))}{\varphi(a)}.
> $$

As long as $\varphi(x)>0$, I don't see why the proof breaks if we admit $X<0$, $a<0$ and extend the domain of $\varphi$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Do we really need those requirements?

Comment: I would state the Markov inequality applying to a non-negative random variable with a finite expectation with any $a>0$ as  $\mathbb P(X \ge a)\le \frac{\mathbb E[X]}{a}$.  If you replace $X$ with non-negative  $\varphi(X)$ etc. then this becomes  $\mathbb P(\varphi(X) \ge \varphi(a))=\frac{\mathbb E[\varphi(X)]}{\varphi(a)}$.  Your argument is that you can in effect invert a suitable $\varphi(X)$ and weaken the conditions on $X$ by instead imposing conditions on $\varphi(X)$  (I think you may need a *strictly* increasing function). Yes, but you have a more complicated result.

Comment: @Henry That looks like an answer to me, not a comment.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I am not sure: I feel as if I am questioning the question

Comment: @Henry, you don't need strict monotonicity. But I agree that the result I get is not as clean as originally stated. Especially, Chebyshev's inequality can't be derived from this result, as $x^2$ isn't monotonically increasing on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Philipp You are probably correct.  I suppose $\mathbb P(X \ge a) \le  \mathbb P(\varphi(X) \ge \varphi(a)) $ even for weakly increasing $\varphi$